# Sending iterable object to base template (ex: ' menus = Menu.objects.all() ')

Tags: python, django, html

When I send

> menus = Menu.objects.all()

through render

> render(request, 'index.html', {'menus': menus})

it did not show me anything, just empty page
But other variables like

> info = Info.objects.last()

is working properly

## this is view.py

'''some code here'''

```
def home(request):
    slides = Slide.objects.order_by('created')[:3]
    main_articles = MainArticle.objects.order_by('created')[:5]
    last_news = News.objects.all()[:4]
    info = OtherInfo.objects.last()
    promo = Promo.objects.last()
    menus = Menu.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'slides': slides,
                                        'main_articles': main_articles,
                                        'last_news': last_news,
                                        'info': info,
                                        'promo': promo,
                                        'menus': menus
                                        })
```

## This is models.py

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)


class SubMenu(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey(Menu, related_name='sub_menu')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} -> {}'.format(self.menu, self.name)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

'''some other models here'''

## this is index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}  

{% block nav_bar %}
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    {% for m in menus.all %}
     {% if m.sub_menu %}
       <li class="dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{ m.name }}<span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         {% for sub in m.sub_menu.all %}
         <li><a href="{% url 'info-ms' menu=m.name submenu=sub.name %}">{{ sub.name }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
         </ul>
       </li>
     {% else %}
       <li>
       <a href="{% url 'info-m' menu=m.name %}">{{ m.name }}</a>
       </li>
     {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: A Menu object doesn't have a `sub_menu` attribute, so your if statement will never be true.

Comment: I used sub_menu because there is relation (ForeignKey) in the SubMenu class with Menu

Answer (score 1):

If you pass:

```
menus = Menu.objects.all()
```

you can use in your template:

```
{% for menu in menus %}
...

    {% if menu.sub_menu.exists %}
        {% for submenu in menu.sub_menu.all %}
        ....
```

You did already call `.all()` in your view.

Comment: I tried to send menus=Menu.objects.all() to base template, but it did not work. I just did not want to write menus on every page.

Comment: So in your template -
 
    {% for menu in menus %}
    <p>{{ menu.name }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

does work?

Comment: yes in the base template which I extended in other templates

Comment: It is now showing any menu item just empty navigation bar